# ion-infinite-scroll not working inside ion-scroll

Tags: html, ionic3, ion-scroll, ion-infinite-scroll

I'm trying to implement load more functionality in the half portion of the page.
So I put that code inside the ion-scroll but somehow current implementation is not working i.g. the method is

```
(ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)"
```

is not triggered and loader UI is not rendered. However, the same implementation is working if the content placed in ion-content instead of ion-scroll.

```
<ion-content padding>
<ion-scroll scrollY="true" id="accountList" class="list-box">
        <ion-list >
          <ion-item *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]">
            <ion-icon ios="ios-add-circle" md="ios-add-circle" item-start color="secondary"></ion-icon>
              Item1
            <ion-buttons item-end>
                  <button ion-button clear icon-only color="orange">
                     <ion-icon ios="md-create" md="md-create" item-end ></ion-icon>
                  </button>
                  <button ion-button clear icon-only color="danger">
                     <ion-icon ios="md-close" md="md-close" item-end></ion-icon>
                  </button>
            </ion-buttons>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
        <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
            <ion-infinite-scroll-content
              loadingSpinner="bubbles"
              loadingText="Loading more data...">
            </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
          </ion-infinite-scroll>
    </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for my bad english, but I resolved this problem by using below code:

```
<ion-scroll #scrollWeb scrollY="true" class="scroll-y">
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-4 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 *ngFor="let item of items">
                <item-card [item]="item"></item-card>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-scroll>
```

And on my component:

```
@ViewChild('scrollWeb') scrollWeb: Scroll;
```

Added listener on `DOM` Element to discover if the scroll arrived in the end as follows:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {   
    if (this.scrollWeb) {
        this.scrollWeb.addScrollEventListener((ev) => {
            if ((ev.target.offsetHeight + ev.target.scrollTop) >= ev.target.scrollHeight) {
                this.doInfinite(null);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In doInfinite function you can omit or show a loader as follows:

```
if (infiniteScroll !== null) {
     infiniteScroll.complete(); 
}
```

Comment: not working for me and once the page is loaded it only works once.

Answer (score 4):

Ionic-version: 3.9.2

I have a similar problem in the component. My solution was:

1. Replace `<ion-scroll>` with `<ion-content>`
2. Add `overflow: auto;` style for `<ion-content>`
3. Enjoy virtual scrolling

Comment: Thank you! You saved me from pulling my hair out. Such an easy solution too.

Answer (score 1):

You need call the $event.complete() method. From the Ionic documentation page of InifniteScroll:

> "The expression assigned to the infinite event is called when the user
>   scrolls to the specified distance. When this expression has finished
>   its tasks, it should call the complete() method on the infinite scroll
>   instance."

Answer (score 0):

ion-Scroll doesn't fire scroll events right now, thus ion-infinite-scroll subscription to scroll events is not fired.
You can try to find some workarounds like firing similar event yourself. I just desided to emulate visual similarity in regular ion-content using css for now (not perfect solution).

Link to issue on Ionic Github: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/13904
Link to issue on forum: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionscroll-event-doesnt-fire-on-ion-scroll/96188/3